# Int to char array using for loop?

Tags: c

I have a

```
char data[2]
```

and also an integer

```
int b = 65535;
```

65535 is in hex 0xffff and it can be putted as following

```
data[0] = 0xff
```

and

```
data[1] = 0xff
```

I have a for loop as following:

```
for(; b > 0; b--) {

}
```

The for loop can not be changed! I want to use a counter, which increments from 0 up to 0xffff and the data looks at each iteration like this:

```
0x0000  <----- first iteration 
0x0001  <----- second iteration 
0x0002  <----- third iteration 
0x0003  <----- fourth iteration 
...... 
0x00ff  <----- 256th iteration 
0x0100  <----- ....
0x0101 
...... 
0xffff
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If `char` is signed, it cannot hold `0xFF`, only `unsigned char` can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use your b counter and xor it with 0xFFFF. Also note the comment about using unsigned char over char for your array.

Smaller Example:

```
b val       xor val
1111   xor  1111    = 0000
1110   xor  1111    = 0001
1101   xor  1111    = 0010
.
.
.
0001   xor  1111    = 1110
0000   xor  1111    = 1111
```

Store it using

```
unsigned short counter = b ^ 0xFFFF;
data[0] = counter & 0xFF;
data[1] = (counter>>8) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Ok, but how can I put them in data[2]?

Comment: Also note that if you want to actually hit 0 as well, you need to do >= not just >

Comment: Ok, but it still does not do what I need. However, thank you.

Comment: data[0] should hold the lower 2 bytes and data[1] should hold the upper 2 bytes each iteration of the loop. What exactly are you trying to achieve once you have those 4 bytes in the data array?

Comment: These two bytes should be putted into data during incrementation, like data = counter++;, where data looks like this: data=0x0000, data=0x0001, data=0x0002, data=0x0003, ... ,data=0xffff. I hope that you understand me what I mean.

Comment: Ok I assumed data was only two chars long since that is what you put in your question. I'll edit the answer accordingly. That being said, I'm still not sure what this actually achieves because your array index is essentially the same value you are storing (i.e. array index 10 stores 0x000A which in decimal is 10). Assuming there is some value to this loop, the solution would be much cleaner if b was incremented vs decremented. I'd strongly consider why you absolutely must have b decremented as you don't gain much in the way of performance if that is the motivation for decrementing b.

Comment: Please note that the data is an array: data[2]. I want to have data = {0xff, 0xff), where there two positions 0 and 1 in the array will be filled using counter that increments from 0 up to  65535 ans as a result I get data = 0xffff. P.S data is not unsigned char. It is just char. And b must be decremented!